# problems with blocking direct access to the file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried to deny direct access to the do.php file via browser. it works but
this file is used in some ajax script so once i use the above code it also blocks file from being called by ajax. or executed, and i want it to be accessed  by other files bt not direct access in browser

```
<Files "do.php">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do isn't really possible, the file must be accessible if you want to use it for AJAX requests, and there's no foolproof way of distinguishing between your AJAX requests and someone trying to request the file manually.

Typically AJAX requests will include an additional `X-Requested-With: XMLHTTPRequest` header.  You could check for that header in your script and if it's not set emit an error.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    http_response_code(403);
    echo 'Direct access denied';
    exit;
}
```

That'd stop your casual user from trying to just open the page in a new browser tab, but it won't stop someone from accessing it using another tool that allows setting headers such as cURL or a scripting language.